# android error when trying to put json data in viewlist php+json+java

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to make a search page for my andriod app using PHP,JSON and SQL.

here is the code that is giving me the error :

```
  try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        int jArrLeng = jArray.length();
        for(int i=0; i<jArrLeng;i++){
            JSONObject json_data= jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            tempID += json_data.getString("ID") + "\n";
            tempID += json_data.getString("heading") + "\n";
            tempID += json_data.getString("rank") + "\n:";

        }

        arr = tempID.split(":");
        resultLV.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr));



    }catch (Exception e){
        String errMsg = "error when putting the json data in the list";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

i have already used this code on another page and it works perfectly but when using it another page/activity it gives me an error when trying to put the json data in listview.

i would guess the problem is when i am setting the ArrayAdapter, have i done anything wrong?

```
resultLV.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr));
```

Comment: What's the actual error being thrown? Sometimes `JSON` requests fail, we need the log to see what `Exception e` is catching.

Comment: Sorry i am a newbie ,how do i through the actual error ?

Comment: e.printstacktrace ();

Comment: ah thanks ! it gave me a serie of errors starting with org.json.JSONExecption:Value test of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSONArray.java:111)

Comment: Your json is not in the right format

Comment: hm i have another page which my home page where i list the last 5 entries in the database and i use exactly the same jsom format and java code :/

Comment: show us your exact JSON, you could be missing a simple  { and it will through the whole thing off

Comment: here is my JSON format:
test[{"ID":"2","heading":"test","ingredients":"test","instructions":"test","hashtag":"test","image":"","rank":"0"}

Comment: Well put that in http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and see what happens, for me it showed an error

Comment: Yes Indeed petro ,you was right ... i just looked in the php file that generate the JSON data and i saw that i have printed the search word(for debuging ) which ruined the format. The error is gone now but i got another one , a nullPointerExecption :/

Comment: OK, now lets see the new error

Comment: `.split(":")` must not be finding `:` or tempId is null

Comment: i check if arr or tempID was null by printing a message , but they was not null. and now i get null exception at line 107 which is `resultLV.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr));`

Comment: So what is `tempID` and `arr` printing out? Why not use an `ArrayList` or `HashMap` for these entries? It would avoid all the splitting. I can tell you from experience using `.split()` like this can turn into a headache if your not careful. Also `.split()` can take in a value like:   `arr=tempID.split(":", 2);` . That would save the first two entries into `arr` which you could then use by : `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`

Comment: Alright .. i just used Android studio debuger and it showed the TempID is empty not null but empty while JArrleng=2

Comment: Check your `json_data.getString("ID")` and make sure all `json_data.`'s are working properly, is `tempID` a String?

Comment: i just tested all json_data.getString and they gave the right value

Comment: ok so doing a `+=` is not working then I would look there or take out your `+ " \n"`

Comment: nope still not working , how funny that the piece of code is a carbon copy of the code on the working page :S

Comment: We'll something is not working with `+=` that i can guarantee

Comment: very weird.. I just restarted andriod studio and now i see that tempID is getting the values but now the array arr is null

Comment: so your .split(":") must not be doing what you thought, try looping through `tempID` and adding that to `arr`

Comment: hmm not sure what to try anymore.. i would like to print the data in a listview and when i click on a item , it have to show items infromations.. do you recommend any other ways ?

Comment: see updated answer, i did all the work for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer your final question:**

```
    //array list
     List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
     try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    int jArrLeng = jArray.length();
    for(int i=0; i<jArrLeng;i++){
        JSONObject json_data= jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        your_array_list.add(json_data.getString("ID") + "\n");
        your_array_list.add(json_data.getString("heading") + "\n");
        your_array_list.add(json_data.getString("rank") + "\n:");

      }
    resultLV.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,your_array_list));
```

---

```
    //then, to get the items from inside the adapter:
    for(String item_in_list : your_array_list){
        System.out.println(item_in_list);
    }
```

---

**To answer the original question:**

Check out http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ for formatting issues

Try looking at this info:
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29

JSONObject

```
public JSONObject(java.lang.String source)
           throws JSONException
```

Construct a JSONObject from a source JSON text string. This is the most commonly used` JSONObject constructor.

```
Parameters:
    source - `A string beginning with { (left brace) and ending with } (right brace).` 
Throws:
    JSONException - If there is a syntax error in the source string or a duplicated key.
```

FYI: The inbuilt JSONObject and JSONArray cannot be used to get certain json responses.

You could try downloading a small library named "json-simple-1.1.1.jar" from this link https://json-simple.googlecode.com/files/json-simple-1.1.1.jar.

Comment: Thanks bro that worked well on my home page but not my search page so there must be something wrong on that page , i am gonna recheck the whole code for search page

Comment: Glad i could help! If you end up needing more help,  just post the link to your new question here so i can find it

Comment: In case you are interested in why it didn't work on my search page , it was because i wrote wrong id for the list >.<  .. Now it works perfectly :D

Comment: Haha that will do it!

Comment: I just gave you a boost, if you don't mind giving this a +1 now :D